# Java Advanced Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

So I have class `Foo` in package `com.one`.

```
//package com.one
class Foo{
     protected static void a(){
         //...
     }
}
```

and class `Bar` in package `com.two` extending `Foo`

```
//package com.two
class Bar extends Foo{
    //...
}
```

Can I use reflection, if I'm inside com.two, to make `a()` not protected, and then call it?

Comment: Set the accessible flag: `method.setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: what does mean to use `protected` with `static`?

Comment: My problem is, how do I properly get this method at runtime?

Comment: Why? [Access is (already) permitted ... within the body of a subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just grab this method and use `setAccessible` with `true`.

To grab this method you can't use `setDeclaredMethod` nor `getMethod` from subclass, because it wasn't declared there or is not public. Easiest way to get it is to do it via superclass like

```
Method method = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("a");
```

or

```
Method method = Bar.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("a");   
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assuming that `a` is declared in superclass,
//                                      it is possible that you may want to use 
//                                      `getSuperclass` few more times
```

then you can just call

```
method.setAccessible(true);
```

to change its accessibility and use it

```
method.invoke(null);//static methods require no instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use reflection for it. Write below code:

```
try {
            Method method = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("a");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                method.invoke(null);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: "*in your Bar*" If `a()` was supposed to be invoked in `Bar` then we wouldn't need reflection since `a()` is part of `Bar` inherited from `Foo` :)

Comment: Agree!! And since Bar is also inherited from Foo, it should be accessible anyways :)

Comment: You need to apparently call the method .getSuperclass() or else it wont appear.

Comment: I am able to get access to "protected" method without using "getSuperclass()". I guess you need getSuperclass() only when you want to use Bar class